# Unable to find Client in FetchEvent for Firefox 44.0.2

Tags: firefox, service-worker, fetch-api

I am using this piece of code to get client. But still it is going to Client Not Matched.

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
var client=null;
if(event.client != null){
    client=event.client;
}else if(event.clientId!=null){
    client=Clients.get(event.clientId);
}else{
    console.log("Client Not Matched.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `client` property is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/client).

The `clientId` property is supported starting from Firefox 45 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/clientId).

Depending on what you need to do, you might be able to use `clients.matchAll` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients).